# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name error

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

So i'm following a tutorial to the t on tkinter, using the python shell. All the imports work, but trying a few methods and properties on a ttk.Button object gives the above error, even though it's exactly like in the tutorial. Namely:

The button has the variable 'button'. Checking the button's 'text' property throws the error using `button['text']` And setting the button's text property via`button.config(text = 'text')` throws the error as well, as does checking config() on the root window. The initial code with imports, ending with the first error yielding line, is:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> from tkinter import ttk
>>> root = Tk()
>>> button = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Button')
>>> button.pack()
>>> button['text']
```

Basically setting or getting the text property of the button or other ttk object throws an error.

Here's the line with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    button['text']
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1483, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!button"
```

Well, actually, according to the tutorial that uses python 3 a Button does have an attribute text.

Edit. I swapped the error message with the relevant one,

Comment: i replaced it with the relevant error.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you also provide a [mcve]? The error  you're getting seems unusual to me.

Comment: Well, as you can see here the first use of button['text'] yielded the above error: >>> from tkinter import *
>>> from tkinter import ttk
>>> root = Tk()
>>> button = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Button')
>>> button.pack()
>>> button['text']
Traceback (most recent call last): # error

Comment: I run the top code snippet and it doesn't give me that error, please provide a script version that produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the widget does not have the variable "`text`". Instead, the options for the widget are stored in a dictionary.

When you use `button["text"]`, you're accessing the item "text" in the dictionary, and so it returns the value of the "text" key. You could also use the `cget` method to get the option.

This dictionary of values is best accessed from the `configure` method. Using said method with no parameters will return a dictionary of all options for the widget.

Comment: Thanks for tryin. But since button['text'] refers to the key's value, and that value is 'Button' (see text = 'Button'), shouldn't it return that value instead of an error, then. Also, should've mentioned, that using button.config() also yields the above error, as does root.config(). it's all error.

Comment: @slackexchange, it's the trying to access the variable "text" that's causing that error, since as I said, the values are not stored in variables, but in the dictionary. Curious that those methods yield errors, I've never had a problem with them.

Comment: i changed the error message to the relevant one, if it helps. It shows that i  used button["text"], which yielded an error. It keeps saying "invalid command name ".!button" even though 'button' is the variable with the button object assigned to it in the ide console, i.e exists. i might just do over.